# Using Anonymous Methods for Exception Logging

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, exception

In our WinForm applications we often have the following try/catch block in our WinForm controls' event handlers:

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
         try
         {
            <code goes here>
         }
         catch (Exception exception)
         {
            Logger.LogError(exception);
         }
      }
```

It was recently proposed that we implement the following:

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) =>
         this.TryCatchLogError(() =>
         {
            {
               <code goes here>;
            }
         });
```

Where

```
public static class Logger
{

    public static void LogError(Exception e)
    {
        <logs the exception>
    }

    public static void TryCatchLogError<T>(this T item, Action action)
    {
         try
         {
            action();
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
            LogError(ex);
         }
     }
    }
}
```

Are there any downsides to this approach? For example, performance issues, thread safety etc...

Comment: I have used that approach before - it is fine (and thread safety should be fine). Performance wise - https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/ . _There will be a perf hit, but a minor one that you are very unlikely to notice._

Comment: They both do the same thing there will be no measurable performance hit. But the first approach is more flexible. Suppose in some cases you need to do something extra or different in the catch block, the first approach lets you do that, the second does not

Comment: I would definitely use the second one, Because it forces developers to follow the rule but the major downfall is writing custom exceptions /actions would be difficult or impossible inside the Logger class

Comment: It seems you are looking for https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

Those are identical in function and the difference in performance would be insignificant.  As a matter of style though, the first seems more readable and flexible.  Readable in that it is very clear what you are doing. Flexible in that you can add additional cleanup in your catch block if needed for those few methods that might need to do something additional.  The second approach is more consistent.  I would favor the first-- but that is a matter of taste.

Answer (score 0):

The stacktrace can get harder to comprehend with anonymous methods.

With Anonymous method:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in WinFormTest.exe
at WinFormTest.MainForm.<button1_Click>b__0() in c:\users\jayv\Documents\Tools\TestApplications\WinFormTest\MainForm.cs:line 19
at WinFormTest.Logger.TryCatchLogError[T](T item, Action action) in \\smbcgroup.com\dfs\users\jvarsani\Documents\Tools\TestApplications\WinFormTest\MainForm.cs:line 49
```

Without Anonymous method:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in WinFormTest.exe
at WinFormTest.MainForm.button2_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\users\jayv\Documents\Tools\TestApplications\WinFormTest\MainForm.cs:line 28
```

The anonymous method includes `.<button1_Click>b__0()` which even experienced people may have to stop and think about for a second. Other than that, all the important details for Line Numbers, method names and files are all there.

Having said that, we do use the Anonymous method style when it comes to showing a Progress Dialog or changing the cursor from Default to Busy

Comment: This consideration for the stack trace is correct.  You should favor this answer over my own-- I did not think of this pitfall to the anonymous method.